# How do I drag and drop pictures into specific picture boxes in arrays? (re-asked, deleted original)

Tags: c#, arrays, drag-and-drop, visual-studio-2017, picturebox

I want to be able to drag and drop an image into any picture box in my array, however when I drag and drop my image into a picture box in that array, the picture box drags into all picture boxes in that array. How do I solve this? Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace finalProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        PictureBox[] Place1 = new PictureBox[8];
        PictureBox[] Place2 = new PictureBox[8];
        PictureBox[] Place3 = new PictureBox[8];
        PictureBox[] Place4 = new PictureBox[8];
        PictureBox[] Place5 = new PictureBox[8];


        System.Random r = new System.Random((int)System.DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            picBananaTreeOG.MouseDown += picBananaTreeOG_MouseDown;


        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //assigning array to planting spots
            Place1[0] = place1;
            Place1[1] = place2;
            Place1[2] = place3;
            Place1[3] = place4;
            Place1[4] = place5;
            Place1[5] = place6;
            Place1[6] = place7;
            Place1[7] = place8;

            Place2[0] = place9;
            Place2[1] = place10;
            Place2[2] = place11;
            Place2[3] = place12;
            Place2[4] = place13;
            Place2[5] = place14;
            Place2[6] = place15;
            Place2[7] = place16;
            Place3[0] = place17;
            Place3[1] = place18;
            Place3[2] = place19;
            Place3[3] = place18;
            Place3[4] = place19;
            Place3[5] = place20;
            Place3[6] = place21;
            Place3[7] = place22;
            Place4[0] = place23;
            Place4[1] = place24;
            Place4[2] = place25;
            Place4[3] = place26;
            Place4[4] = place27;
            Place4[5] = place28;
            Place4[6] = place29;
            Place4[7] = place30;
            Place5[0] = place31;
            Place5[1] = place32;
            Place5[2] = place33;
            Place5[3] = place34;
            Place5[4] = place35;
            Place5[5] = place36;
            Place5[6] = place37;
            Place5[7] = place38;
            for (int i = 0; i < Place1.Length; i++)
            {
                Place1[i].AllowDrop = true;
                Place1[i].DragEnter += Place1_DragEnter;
                Place1[i].DragDrop += Place1_DragDrop;
            }

        }


        private void picBananaTreeOG_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var img = picBananaTreeOG.Image;
            if (img == null) return;

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                picBananaTreeOG.DoDragDrop(picBananaTreeOG.Image,
                    DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }

                picBananaTreeOG.Image = picBananaTreeOG.Image;

        }



       private void Place1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
            }
        }
        private void Place1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Place1.Length; i++)
            {

                Place1[i].Image = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);
            }


        }



    }
}
```

picBananaOG is the picture I am dragging. The array name is Place1. I only want the picture to drag to the picture I am dragging it to, but it keeps dragging to every picture in the array. I am only doing this for the Place1 array, so ignore the others.

Comment: __You__ add it to every pbox. Cast sender to  picturebox and only drop it there : `((PictureBox(sender)).Image = ...`

Comment: @TaW where do i put that in the code though?

Comment: In your common Place1_DragDrop event, replacing the loop

Comment: @TaW I'm not very experienced so I'm confused at what you mean and what the ellipses are supposed to represent.

Comment: The rest of your assignment code, of course : `= (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);` assuming it is working..